# F# Codelens locale

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

I'm using VSCode and Ionide extension.

VSCode language is English, so I want Code lens also in English, but It doesn't.

[image: VSCode F# Code lens locale]

How can I change Code lens language?